# How to group multiple array elements from first array, and assign it to second array's first element

Tags: angular, typescript, logic

I have a array, looks like:

```
public static readonly List: Array<any> = [
    { name: 'CCS', link: 'Dummy link1' },
    { name: 'CCR', link: 'Dummy link2' },
    { name: 'PM', link: 'Dummy link3' },
    { name: 'CM', link: 'Dummy link4' },
    { name: 'JM', link: 'Dummy link5' },
    { name: 'PSM', link: 'Dummy link6' }
];
```

What I want to do is, take every 3 elements od the List array, and create another array as follows:

```
ArrayFinal[{
             { name: 'CCS', link: 'Dummy link1' },
             { name: 'CCR', link: 'Dummy link2' },
             { name: 'PM', link: 'Dummy link3' }
           },
           {
             { name: 'CM', link: 'Dummy link4' },
             { name: 'JM', link: 'Dummy link5' },
             { name: 'PSM', link: 'Dummy link6' }
           }]
```

I am trying to do it like find modulus of 3 ===0, and then go to next, but not sure much how to do it.

Any help would be very helpful.

**UPDATE**
What I have tried:

```
public func(): any {
    for (let i = 1; i <= Array.List.length; i++) {
        if (i % 3 === 0) {
            this.ArrayFinal[i] = [Array.List[i], Array.List[i - 1], 
            Array.List[i - 2]];
        }
    }
```

This is somehow skipping the 1st element....and I am totally lost now on why

Comment: Not really elaborated as an answer, but you could loop through the array from 3 to 3 elements (instead of 1 by 1), use `Array.prototype.slice()` to extract the 3 elements at a time and `push` then on a new array.

Comment: Could you recheck the syntax of `ArrayFinal`? That does not look like valid syntax.

Comment: @DeborahK that is valid

Comment: If I simply paste the `ArrayFinal` line exactly as you have it into Stackblitz (inside a component), I get an error `';' expected`. Minimally, it seems that it should have an `=`?

Comment: okay..thanks for that @DeborahK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to convert this:

```
List: Array<any> = [
    { name: 'CCS', link: 'Dummy link1' },
    { name: 'CCR', link: 'Dummy link2' },
    { name: 'PM', link: 'Dummy link3' },
    { name: 'CM', link: 'Dummy link4' },
    { name: 'JM', link: 'Dummy link5' },
    { name: 'PSM', link: 'Dummy link6' }
  ];
```

to this:

```
[ 
  [ 
    { "name": "CCS", "link": "Dummy link1" },
    { "name": "CCR", "link": "Dummy link2" }, 
    { "name": "PM", "link": "Dummy link3" }
  ], 
  [ 
    { "name": "CM", "link": "Dummy link4" }, 
    { "name": "JM", "link": "Dummy link5" }, 
    { "name": "PSM", "link": "Dummy link6" }
  ]
]
```

Using the following code:

```
from(this.List).pipe(
  bufferCount(3)
).subscribe(x => this.groupedList.push(x));
```

The `from` creates an observable from the array.

The `bufferCount(3)` buffers three elements at a time.

Each time 3 elements are emitted from the observable, they are pushed into an element of the `groupedList` array.

Here is the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-buffer-count-deborahk

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with array `slice` and `splice` operations. `slice` source array then push to target array with `array spread(...)` then `splice` source array. loop untill source has items.

```
    while (Math.ceil(source.length / 3) >= 1) {
        target.push({...source.slice(0,3)});
        source.splice(0,3);
    }
```